# Backtrack, Wi-Fi not working

Tags: wireless-networking, backtrack

I've installed Backtrack 5R3 KDE, and I realized that my wireless is not working, but wired is working fine.

Here's the `lshw` output:

```
   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        logical name: eth0
        version: 05
        serial: 04:7d:7b:b7:46:f8
        size: 100MB/s
        capacity: 100MB/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100MB/s
        resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

`lspci` output:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: The lspci output might be more appropriate here.

Comment: @BatchyX - There it is...

Comment: Try finding out what wireless adapter you have. Try following the instructions provided here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-wireless-driver-chipset/ (I'm noticing there's a lack of the phrase "wireless" in your `lspci` output)

Comment: @bigbadonk420 - i don't any wireless there...
I forgot say, that under Windows, wireless was working...
My laptop should have 'Intel’s Centrino Wireless-N 2200 adapter'

Comment: Have you tried googling for a driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved it.
I've downloaded appropriate driver from http://intellinuxwireless.org and put it to /lib/firmware...